# DNS Server Search order in Windows 10 and VPNs

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, vpn, powershell

#### DNS queries to hosts accessible through a VPN fail. How to fix?

On a Windows 10 host, DNS queries for hosts known only to the VPN-accessible DNS Server fail to resolve.  The DNS queries are sent to my local DNS Server (`192.168.1.1`) which returns no DNS Answers. DNS queries are not sent to the VPN-accessible DNS Server (`10.0.1.1`).

##### Technical Information

Powershell `Get-DnsClientServerAddress` shows:

```
PS> Get-DnsClientServerAddress
InterfaceAlias               Interface Address ServerAddresses
                             Index     Family
--------------               --------- ------- ---------------
Ethernet                            10 IPv4    {192.168.1.1}
Ethernet                            10 IPv6    {}
VPN                                 20 IPv4    {10.0.1.1}
VPN                                 20 IPv6    {}
```

Pinging the VPN DNS Server succeeds (`ping 10.0.1.1`).
Resolving a DNS name of `google.com` succeeds (`Resolve-DnsName google.com`).
However, resolving a DNS name of VPN-accessible host `server.corp.com` fails.

```
PS> Resolve-DNSName server.corp.com
PS>
```

**How can I force DNS queries to prefer the VPN-accessible DNS Server at `10.0.1.1`?**

Answer (score 3):

#### Change the `InterfaceMetric` for the `VPN` interface to be lower in value (more important) than the local `Ethernet` interface.

Using `Get-NetIPInterface`, the interface metrics were

```
PS> Get-NetIPInterface
ifIndex InterfaceAlias AddressFamily NlMtu(Bytes) InterfaceMetric Dhcp     ConnectionState PolicyStore
------- -------------- ------------- ------------ --------------- ----     --------------- -----------
10      Ethernet       IPv4                  1500            4000 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
20      VPN            IPv4                  1400              35 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
```

**Using [`Set-NetIPInterface`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/set-netipinterface?view=windowsserver2019-ps)
I changed the `VPN` interface property `InterfaceMetric` to lower integer value `15` for `AddressFamily IPv4` (requires Administrator permissions)**

```
PS> Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex 20 -InterfaceMetric 15
```

Now the DNS queries for hosts known to the VPN-accessible DNS Server will succeed.

```
PS> Resolve-DNSName server.corp.com
Name                  Type   TTL   Section    IPAddress
----                  ----   ---   -------    ---------
server.corp.com       A      130   Answer     10.0.1.2
```